# How to idiomatically alias a crate in Rust 2018?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-2018

I have a crate `foo_sys`. In Rust 2015 I used `extern crate foo_sys as foo` for convenience, but in Rust 2018 `extern crate` isn't needed anymore and I don't want to use it only for aliasing. When dropping `extern crate`, I get

> error[[E0463]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0463): can't find crate for `foo`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [*rename-dependency*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html?highlight=rename,depende#renaming-dependencies-in-cargotoml) Cargo feature, [available in Rust 1.31](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html#cargo-features). With this feature, it's possible to provide a package attribute to the dependencies:

> The rename-dependency feature allows you to import a dependency with a different name from the source. This can be useful in a few scenarios:
>
> - Depending on crates with the same name from different registries.
> - Depending on multiple versions of a crate.
> - **Avoid needing `extern crate foo as bar` in Rust source.**

Instead of writing

```
[dependencies]
foo_sys = "0.2"
```

the `package` key can be added to the dependency in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
foo = { package = "foo_sys", version = "0.2" }
```

**WARNING**: [Cargo prior to Rust 1.26.0 may download the wrong dependency](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/security/advisories/GHSA-phjm-8x66-qw4r) when using this feature!

Answer (score 11):

The idiomatic solution is to rename the crate in `Cargo.toml`. See [the answer by Tim Diekmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51508848/2408867) for more information about that.

But if you don't want to use `Cargo.toml` renaming for some reason, you can still use the old syntax. It's soft-deprecated, but not removed. So this still works:

```
extern crate foo_sys as foo;
```

([Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1941b5de4e99863fdaa3f08a4b64be1e))

Comment: Not that as of end of 2023, it's the only way to rename a crate inherited from a workspace: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/12546