# How can I use the futures 0.1 and futures-preview 0.3 crates at the same time?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to use both `futures-preview` and `futures` in my project. My Cargo.toml looks like:

```
[dependencies]
futures-preview = "= 0.3.0-alpha.7"
futures = "0.1.25"
```

Now, in my `lib.rs`, when I do

```
extern crate futures;
```

Rust got confused about which futures crate to use. How can I use these two crates that have the same `extern crate` name at the same time?

```
   Compiling spdk-rs v0.1.0 (/home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/spdk-rs)
error[E0465]: multiple rlib candidates for `futures` found
  --> /home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/spdk-rs/src/lib.rs:17:1
   |
17 | extern crate futures;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: candidate #1: /home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/examples/hello_nvme_bdev_rust_wrapper/target/debug/deps/libfutures-ac8c40146fd4a4e0.rlib
  --> /home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/spdk-rs/src/lib.rs:17:1
   |
17 | extern crate futures;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2: /home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/examples/hello_nvme_bdev_rust_wrapper/target/debug/deps/libfutures-44db24e7af1a2bd3.rlib
  --> /home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/spdk-rs/src/lib.rs:17:1
   |
17 | extern crate futures;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `futures`
  --> /home/zeyuanhu/share/rustfs/spdk-rs/src/lib.rs:17:1
   |
17 | extern crate futures;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to alias a crate in Rust 2018 idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50999616/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR, use the `package` key in your Cargo.toml for one of the dependencies.

Comment: That works! Thanks!